# Gitlab CI how to use multiple images for build?

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab

My problem is quite simple, i have java maven project and i need to build docker image of it.
So for building with docker runner i could use image like maven:3.3.9-jdk-8, but for building image i need different image of docker in docker.
And i cant understand how i could use multiple images inside pipline and transfer file between them?
So as i understand process image maven:3.3.9-jdk-8 should build ***.jar and then image like docker:19.03.12 should build a docker. But i cant find a clue how to do this... All gitlab docs explain one image usage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok appear that you could access artifacts from previous jobs, just using same paths and it work... But strange that i cant find any clue about it in gitlab doc. Only such phrase
"By default, jobs in later stages automatically download all the artifacts created by jobs in earlier stages."